# How can a custom audio effect produce some sound after a AudioFileInputNode has finished playing

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, signal-processing

I'm developping an audio application in C# and UWP using the AudioGraph API.
My AudioGraph setup is the following :
AudioFileInputNode --> AudioSubmixNode --> AudioDeviceOutputNode.

I attached a custom echo effect on the AudioSubmixNode.
If I play the AudioFileInputNode I can hear some echo.
But when the AudioFileInputNode playback finishes, the echo sound stops brutally.
I would like it to stop gradually after few seconds only.
If I use the EchoEffectDefinition from the AudioGraph API, the echo sound is not stopped after the sample playback has finished.

I don't know if the problem comes from my effect implementation or if it's a strange behavior of the AudioGraph API...
The behavior is the same in the "AudioCreation" sample in the SDK, scenario 6.

Here is my custom effect implementation :

```
public sealed class AudioEchoEffect : IBasicAudioEffect
{
    public AudioEchoEffect()
    {
    }

    private readonly AudioEncodingProperties[] _supportedEncodingProperties = new AudioEncodingProperties[]
    {
        AudioEncodingProperties.CreatePcm(44100, 1, 32),
        AudioEncodingProperties.CreatePcm(48000, 1, 32),
    };

    private AudioEncodingProperties _currentEncodingProperties;
    private IPropertySet _propertySet;

    private readonly Queue<float> _echoBuffer = new Queue<float>(100000);
    private int _delaySamplesCount;

    private float Delay
    {
        get
        {
            if (_propertySet != null && _propertySet.TryGetValue("Delay", out object val))
            {
                return (float)val;
            }
            return 500.0f;
        }
    }

    private float Feedback
    {
        get
        {
            if (_propertySet != null && _propertySet.TryGetValue("Feedback", out object val))
            {
                return (float)val;
            }
            return 0.5f;
        }
    }

    private float Mix
    {
        get
        {
            if (_propertySet != null && _propertySet.TryGetValue("Mix", out object val))
            {
                return (float)val;
            }
            return 0.5f;
        }
    }

    public bool UseInputFrameForOutput { get { return true; } }

    public IReadOnlyList<AudioEncodingProperties> SupportedEncodingProperties { get { return _supportedEncodingProperties; } }

    public void SetProperties(IPropertySet configuration)
    {
        _propertySet = configuration;
    }

    public void SetEncodingProperties(AudioEncodingProperties encodingProperties)
    {
        _currentEncodingProperties = encodingProperties;

        // compute the number of samples for the delay
        _delaySamplesCount = (int)MathF.Round((this.Delay / 1000.0f) * encodingProperties.SampleRate);

        // fill empty samples in the buffer according to the delay
        for (int i = 0; i < _delaySamplesCount; i++)
        {
            _echoBuffer.Enqueue(0.0f);
        }
    }

    unsafe public void ProcessFrame(ProcessAudioFrameContext context)
    {
        AudioFrame frame = context.InputFrame;

        using (AudioBuffer buffer = frame.LockBuffer(AudioBufferAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        using (IMemoryBufferReference reference = buffer.CreateReference())
        {
            ((IMemoryBufferByteAccess)reference).GetBuffer(out byte* dataInBytes, out uint capacity);
            float* dataInFloat = (float*)dataInBytes;
            int dataInFloatLength = (int)buffer.Length / sizeof(float);

            // read parameters once
            float currentWet = this.Mix;
            float currentDry = 1.0f - currentWet;
            float currentFeedback = this.Feedback;

            // Process audio data
            float sample, echoSample, outSample;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataInFloatLength; i++)
            {
                // read values
                sample = dataInFloat[i];
                echoSample = _echoBuffer.Dequeue();

                // compute output sample
                outSample = (currentDry * sample) + (currentWet * echoSample);
                dataInFloat[i] = outSample;

                // compute delay sample
                echoSample = sample + (currentFeedback * echoSample);
                _echoBuffer.Enqueue(echoSample);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Close(MediaEffectClosedReason reason)
    {
    }

    public void DiscardQueuedFrames()
    {
        // reset the delay buffer
        _echoBuffer.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < _delaySamplesCount; i++)
        {
            _echoBuffer.Enqueue(0.0f);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT :
I changed my audio effect to mix the input samples with a sine wave. The ProcessFrame effect method runs continuously before and after the sample playback (when the effect is active). So the sine wave should be heared before and after the sample playback. But the AudioGraph API seems to ignore the effect output when there is no active playback...

Here is a screen capture of the audio output :
[image]

So my question is : How can the built-in EchoEffectDefinition output some sound after the playback finished ? An access to the EchoEffectDefinition source code would be a great help...

Comment: I used the code in the "AudioCreation" sample, scenario 4 which contains AudioSubmixNode and added your custom echo effect on its AudioSubmixNode, when the AudioFileInputNode playback finished, the echo sound could stop gradually after few seconds. Do you mean when you used it with your echo effect, the echo sound will stop mmediately? You could try to return the Delay value as 1000.0f in your custom echo effect, echo delay will be more noticeable, you can check it.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Faywang-MSFT. I tried my custom audio effect in the scenario 4 and the problem is the same. Try to load a very short sample (a drum sound for example). If the sample length is 1.5 sec and my delay is 0.5 sec, then I can hear only 2 echoes. It seems that the output sound of my custom effect is brutally cut when the sample playback has finished... It should continue and decrease gradually (the built-in Echo does that). I tried also to record the speakers output with Audacity and when I watch the sound curve, it is clear that my echo is cut at the end of the sample playback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By infinitely looping the file input node, then it will always provide an input frame until the audio graph stops. But of course we do not want to hear the file loop, so we can listen the FileCompleted event of AudioFileInputNode. When the file finishes playing, it will trigger the event and we just need to set the OutgoingGain of AudioFileInputNode to zero. So the file playback once, but it continues to silently loop passing input frames that have no audio content to which the echo can be added.

Still using scenario 4 in the AudioCreation sample as an example. In the scenario4, there is a property named fileInputNode1. As mentioned above, please add the following code in fileInputNode1 and test again by using your custom echo effect.

```
fileInputNode1.LoopCount = null; //Null makes it loop infinitely
fileInputNode1.FileCompleted += FileInputNode1_FileCompleted;          

private void FileInputNode1_FileCompleted(AudioFileInputNode sender, object args)
{
    fileInputNode1.OutgoingGain = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't had the idea of using a loop. This will surely work ! But in my real application, I think I will use instead an AudioFrameInputNode that generates some empty frames in the submix node. As I already use the looping for other purposes... I still consider it's a hack. We should have a property on the IBasicAudioEffect to control this behavior...